# Json deserialization onto readonly fields in C#

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have a readonly struct. The struct, as it is readonly,must have readonly fields. However, I cannot apparently deserialize onto these fields from json. I would much like to keep my struct readonly though. How can I deserialize json to a readonly struct?

I am using the built-in json (System.Text.Json)

Comment: It's unclear which JSON framework you're using. For System.Text.Json, I believe the `[JsonConstructor]` attribute is the way forward.

Comment: Right added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `JsonConstructor`, as pointed out by @JonSkeet. However, if you want to have a struct without custom constructor, this is adressed in .Net 8, which releases this month, so if this is an option for you, I would recommend .Net 8.

Here is the explaination: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8#read-only-properties

Comment: That sounds convenient!